# How to handle two different forms in an asp.net web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication

I have a login page in my asp.net website (using C#) and it has a "login form" which has an email text box, a password text box and a login button.

In addition, I have a "search form" at the top of the web page which has a search text box and a search button.

*All of the controls are in the same form because of the asp.net limit for one `runat="server"` form.

The problem is that when I type something to search for and click ENTER (and not directly the button) it doesn't do anything, only runs the Page_Load again. Same thing when I click ENTER in the login section instead of directly on the login button.

I have tried different solutions but they were problematic because of the different functionality of the two "forms".

***I have no idea how to solve this, any suggestions?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my web forms is a little rusty but I think something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="loginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="loginButton">
<%-- Login Stuff--%>
<asp:Button ID="loginButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>


<asp:Panel ID="loginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="searchButton">
<%-- Search Stuff --%>
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

should work

Comment: Yep, this should do it. Also you can use the `ValidationGroup` attribute to trigger specific validation controls (or not) depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: That works :) I converted the search to normal html for simplicity, but this solved the ENTER issue. Is that the only way to change the default button of a web page?

Comment: In web forms i think default button is the only way to go.  In mvc or vanilla html you can just use multiple forms.

Answer (score 0):

Only one form with `runat='server'` available on aspx page. So, if you really need another form, you may use its without `runat='server'` and use for search jQuery ajax call.